# Call to REST web service results in response of error 503 but not with a tool like Poster

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to send an xml document to a REST web service. Using a tool like Poster, the call works fine (With the xml in the body of the "content"), but in my code, I get error 503 server unavailable.

Link to Poster:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/

My code is as follows (this is a test-harness so no error handling etc):

```
    string s = "";

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\users\dev.admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\XMLFile1.xml"))
    {
        s = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    string url = FULL_URL_WITH_PARAMETERS; // SAME URL AS USED IN POSTER

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";

    string data = s;  

    Stream postStream = null;

    using (StreamWriter requestStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {

        requestStream.Write(data);
    }

    HttpWebResponse pervasiveResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(pervasiveResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    string backstr = sr1.ReadToEnd();
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```

Comment: have you tried using anything like Fiddler to compare the outgoing HTTP requests? This may uncover differences in headers, cookies, or the body itself

Comment: I didn't do this due to time constraints, but will try it tomorrow. Just wanted to ensure that the code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST Starter Kit? WCF Web API (Glenn Block's project, now part of AppFabric int he 4.5 time frame? (although I believe there will be a standalone))? Roll your own joint?

Regardless, I think working with binary is the correct method to go. For that reason, I would start with something like [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor). Not because I tried the code and think it is a great article, but merely because the article shows sending XML and I don't have time to find the client I wrote a few months ago. ;-)

If I can break free long enough to find my code, I will post a sample.

Oh, another tool you should look at is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). No, it is not just for testing SOAP, as it supports REST (and other methodologies) as well as SOAP. One nice benefit of using SoapUI is the ability to move the tests over to [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) and stress testing a service. If you are merely consuming services, it might not have the greatest value, of course.